# Providing Firebase Auth, Firebase User and Firebase Database Reference as dependencies to Presenter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, mvp, dagger-2

I'm making a simple project using Firebase Authentication and Database. I want to use Dagger2 to provide database reference to my Presenter. But I'm not sure that what I'm doing would actually work...
Here's my DataModule:

> @Module public class DataModule {

```
FireBaseApp mFirebaseApp;

public DataModule(FireBaseApp fireBaseApp) {
    this.mFirebaseApp = fireBaseApp;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
FirebaseAuth getFirebaseAuth() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
FirebaseUser getCurrentUser(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    return firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
IPosts providePosts() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference();
    return new PostRepository(databaseReference);
}
```

My Component:

```
>  @Singleton @Component(modules = DataModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

void inject(AddPostActivity addPostActivity);
```

}

Application class:

```
public class FireBaseApp extends Application {

private ApplicationComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
    }

    inject();

}

private void inject() {
    component = DaggerApplicationComponent
            .builder()
            .dataModule(new DataModule(this))
            .build();
}

public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent(){
    return component;
}
```

}

And finally Presenter:

```
public class PostRepository implements IPosts {

DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

public PostRepository(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    this.mDatabaseReference = Preconditions.checkNotNull(databaseReference);

}

@Override
public Observable getPost(String title) {
    Query query = mDatabaseReference
            .child("users")
            .child("")
            .child("posts")
            .orderByChild("title");
    return observe(query);

}
```

/// etc...
This is how I got it working before going for MVP and Dagger. In my MainActivity:

```
private void initFireBase() {
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
}
```

And to save a Post to Databse:

```
Post post = new Post(mEditTextTitle.getText().toString(), mEditTextBody.getText().toString());            mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("posts").push().setValue(post);
```

I feel like I'm not doing it correctly using Dagger2. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to add my Interface: ```public interface IPosts {

    Observable sendPost(Post post);

    Observable getPost(String title);
}```

Comment: This looks generally ok. Are you running into any issues?

Comment: Not yet. But the thing is I need ```mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser``` in ```public Observable getPost(String title)``` So can I just inject it to ```public class PostRepository implements IPosts``` ???